# What is the relationship between the container, the blocks and the bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css, containers, grid-layout

I have started learning coding on freecodecamp and got confused with the containers, inline vs block vs inline-block and the bootstrap 12 column system.

- **What is the difference** between a container and a block?
- Do I absolutely need both and **why**?
- If I use bootstrap, **why** do I need to know about inline vs block elements? I can just use Bootstrap "col-xs-12" for example and it won't matter whether my elements are inline or block because they will take the formatting of the parent element.

I have searched for the difference between containers and block (inline-block) but it only explains what each of them does and as far as I understood, they do the same thing, divide the website into blocks that can be styled and resized. Blocks would be placed in containers but here again, what's the purpose of containers if we have blocks.

(Among other results, found that: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/div-containers-div-wrappers which does not answer my question and got me to ask myself what a wrapper was and that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/All_About_The_Containing_Block but this article got me even more confused)

I'm a total beginner and am sorry if my question comes as very basic for most but I really need to understand the concept. Thank you whoever helps out!

Comment: simply do more research and read more .. by the way your question is out off-topic here

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I have looked for an answer for the past 2 days but I don't need to read about what is what. I need to understand the difference. Why is my question off topic? Is there another place I shall have posted it?

Comment: because your question is not related to a programming issue ... it's related to `i need to learn more stuffs` and for that you need to read more even if you don't want, because we cannot learn without reading

Comment: Hello Elly and welcome to stackoverflow. Nice that you are here. Although your question seems absolutely legit to me, I have to admit that @TemaniAfif is partially right with what he says. I recon your read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as your question is well structured, so I will give it a try and answer your question as good as I can :-)

Comment: I think CSS concepts are generally very poorly taught. Mostly tutorials have a cookbook style that is very unhelpful when trying to gain a deeper understanding. Essentailly, CSS is the layout of *boxes*. A block is a type of box that follows certain rules. A container represents a relationship of one box to another - container-of/contained-within.

Comment: Thank you Xan-Kun Clark-Davis and Alohci for answering my question and sorry for the late answer. @Alohci: I tried Udemy tutorials and w3schools as well and believe I get a grasp of what is what but now I got to understand the relationship between them thanks to your explanation!

Comment: @Clark-Davis: To be honest, after reading the comment of Temani, I tried staying away from Stack Overflow and went straight away to Free Code Camp where I got an answer as well. I will indeed come back once I gather more knowledge about coding.

Answer (score 0):

It is of uttermost importance to understand the meaning of the technical terms correctly and adapt them to the context. `inline`, `block` and `inline-block` are well defined words in the HTML specification. I am not sure which `container` you exactly refer to, as it is not clear from the context. Do you mean [css-containers](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_containers.asp)?

`bootstrap` is a framework, which is itself not part of the HTML specification.

`freecodecamp` uses many frameworks and seems to be very popular, but they do not have a dedicated stackoverflow policy, in contrary, they host their own forum.

In this regard, your question is off-topic here and should be posted here:
https://forum.freecodecamp.org/

They even say

> Our forum is like Stack Overflow for campers

Hope I could help and when you learned more about HTML, CSS and JavaScript and encounter your first real "bug", come back here and we will figure it out :-)

BTW, I like w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

A little more concrete: There are elements, that will have "their own" line, these are the usual block elements. Then there are inline elements, that are embedded in the current line flow. The important fact to be aware of here is: All these HTML elements come with a default css configuration, which you can change! So it is totally possible to make a div (by default a 'block' element) become an `inline` element by specifying different css. Also vice versa, you can make a span behave like a `block` element by overwriting it's default css. The CSS pane in the firefox console can show you all the css rules involved for each element. That means it can show you not only the styles you defined, but also the default styles, that every element comes with.

Nevertheless, it is important to understand what is meant with `block` as the "new line" apporach is only a simplification of what's going on. It also seems like a good idea, to use the HTML element, that't the closest to what I want and change it's behaviour. If it is an ad on the right side for example, you would use a `div` and go from there, instead of, let's say a `span` and trying to bend that to your will (which is totally possible, but leads to problematic and unintuitive code).

When I started with HMTL and CSS, it was very helpful to have to HTML code and the rendered web page side by side. It helped my learning process significantly. I used Dreamweaver (not sure if that still exists) and nowadays all you might need is jsfiddle and a development firefox (just a regular firefox with a bunch of extensions, that make development easier). I used Firebug in the old days, but now every major browser comes with a console, debugging features and live code editing. Just hit F12 in firefox and habe fun :-)

Comment: Yes I meant css-containers. I checked the link you sent and I had already read it. The confusion was here for me:
"The <div> element is often used as a container for other HTML elements."
"When used together with CSS, the <div> element can be used to style blocks of content"
And on other websites, they use "block" and "containers" interchangeably sometimes but it supposed to be different...
I am now understanding a little bit better and keep learning so I shall get there!
And I'll come back, thank you for helping out!

Comment: I added some (hopefully :-) ) insights to the answer, if you feel like it helped, make sure to accept the answer by clicking the check mark.